# How to fill a tablecolumn with an Arraylist in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I m trying to fill a table column with a String ArrayList. Normally i know how to fill it with object attributes but in my case i just need to fill it with Strings from an ArrayList.
How can i do it ?

through the answer which i got still it doesnt seems to work :(

```
table = new TableView(FXCollections.observableArrayList(id));

            linkC.setCellValueFactory((p) -> {
                return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue());
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, it just may not be the best idea.  Tables are designed to be used with a class of data.  A single column table is just a list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<String> tv = new TableView(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                    "a","bb","ccc","dddd","eeeee"
                }))));
        TableColumn<String, String> tc = new TableColumn<>("string");
        tc.setCellValueFactory((p) -> {
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue());
        });
        tv.getColumns().add(tc);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tv));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: but when i try to fill 2 table columns with different arraylists i get both of them with the same data.

Comment: There's no way I can think of to do that.  You'd have to combine them into rows somehow first.  A table is a 2d representation of one class with a row for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

example below:

```
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
doubles.add(12.12d);
ObservableList<Double> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(doubles);
ListView<Double> listView = new ListView<Double>(names);
```

Comment: But i need to add the arraylist in a  tableColumn and not in listview.. Is there a way to do such a thing or do i need to use a listview instead ?